# Forward and backward between links without reloading page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have six pages named:

```
page1a.php
page1b.php
page1c.php
page1d.php
page2a.php
page2b.php
```

Each page contains

```
<button class="back">Back</button>
<button class="forward">Forward</button>
<div class="content">content inside, different for each page</div>
```

For example, say that I currently am visiting page2a.php.

When I click `<button class="forward">` I would like to be relocated to page2b.php without reloading page, and `<button class="back">` should take me to page1d.php but without the full refreshing that happens when you press the browser's forward and backward buttons. Instead I would like to have a seamless transition to the next page.

The forward button should be disabled when I am on the last page, and the backward button disabled on first page.

If I add more pages in the future, like page1e.php, it should also work without having to change the code.

Is this possible somehow with jQuery/Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

If you click on "forward" / "backward", what you are doing is telling your browser to load that page, which means he automatically reloads it. You can't tell him not to reload the page, because then he wouldn't load it at all. Or what do you exactly mean by "reloading"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$( "#result" ).load("ajax/test.html");
```

to load the contents with in the particular element